# How to use app.locals with .findOne in Mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose, partials

I want to find the logged in user, and set their info to `app.locals` so that I can use it in any view.

I'm setting it up in my `server.js` file like so:

```
app.use(ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.session.passport.user }, (err, user) => {
    console.log('user\n', user)
    app.locals.logged_in_user = user;
    next();
  })
});
```

`console.log('user\n', user)` confirms that the user has been found.
Then, I should be able to use this user's info in any partial, such as in my `layout.hbs` file like so:

```
Currently, {{logged_in_user}} is logged in.
```

But, it's not working.  The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377200/how-to-use-app-locals-inside-app-get-in-express-and-parse) suggested to use `res.locals` instead, but that didn't work.  The example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452123/how-to-create-global-variables-accessible-in-all-views-using-express-node-js) uses static data, but I need dynamic data since `user` will depend on who's logged in.

Right now, I have to define the `user` variable in every route.  Is there a way to globally define a `user` variable that can be used in any partial?

Comment: `res.locals` is the correct object to add dynamic information to, `app.locals` is for static (set once) information only. Is your middleware declared before the route(s) that render the templates? Inside those routes, just before calling `res.render()`, what is the value of `res.locals.logged_in_user`?

Comment: I just took out `ensureAuthenticated` and it worked.  But thanks for the reply!

Comment: Still, don't use `app.locals`. Or, if you do, expect that you can only have one active user at all times.

Comment: You're right: I used `res.locals` and it worked as expected.  But, it's good to know that I can use `app.locals` for static data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using passport judging from the code. The [documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs) states the following:

> If authentication succeeds, the next handler will be invoked and the `req.user` property will be set to the authenticated user.

Therefore you can do the following (or however you want to do it):

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.user = req.user
  next()
}
```

This will pass the user object to all requests and the views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I'm using passport.  I think your answer makes sense if I wasn't looking up the user in my database.  However, I'm running `User.findOne` to look the user up in my database.  I then want to pass that user object that's returned from the db to a `res.locals` variable.  So, `app.use((req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ _id: req.session.passport.user }, (err, user) => {
    res.locals.logged_in_user = user;
    next();
  })
});`

Comment: @Farid with a proper Passport setup, `passport.deserializeUser` would have already looked up the user.

Comment: Taking out `ensureAuthenticated` worked.  Thanks guys.

Comment: I tried this again, but using `req.locals` instead of `res.locals`, and it doesn't seem to work.  My app just hangs.  Did you mean to write `res.locals`?  Because that works.

Comment: @Farid you are correct. I've edited the answer. https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals